# Gparted, fdisk with reference to Install

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I believe this is a different problem from a set of fdisk, gparted questions already asked and answered.

gparted reports the partition as `/dev/sda` as ntfs.  I would have expected the partition to be reported as sda2 or sda4.

[image: Gparted output]

`fdisk`, `fixparts`, and Windows disk show the full set of expected partitions ( /root, /home, /var, swap,  C (ntfs),  D (ntfs)).

sfdisk reports:

[image: sfdisk output]

so I think the partitions **are** there, but gparted and the install partitioner are reporting the only partition as  '/dev/sda'.

**How do I take the content of sfdisk or fdisk and write the partition information so that gparted reads the same set of partition data/meta-data?**

I think I can fix the other issues when the data that gparted uses matches the actual partitions.

### note: I do not want to wipe out all the existing partitions by re-init'ing parted.

After the last xubuntu upgrade in place, the mount partitions were not being recognized.  I had thought it might have been an issue with disk uid's and the boot scripts would drop me into emergency root access. I backed up my work directories and attempted to do a fresh install from LiveCD, where this problem makes itself evidenced.

Comment: Post a screen shot?  Or at least the output of `parted -l`, which *should* agree with what gparted says.

Comment: Your question is missing critical details, such as *actual* program output. (General tip: *Always* show *real* program output, such as cut-and-pasted text-mode output or screen shots. Summaries almost invariably omit critical information.) That said, I suspect you may be encountering [this problem.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/missing-parts/index.html)

Comment: from a install error on laptop, it is difficult to save a screenshot :-)  Let me see if I can get the same state from the LiveCD.  Again the problem is that gparted is reporting a partition as **sda**  where normally partitions are **sda2** or **sdc4**.

Comment: Try double-clicking the ! icon in the list, then post a screenshot the the resulting dialog.

Answer (score 0):

While I do not **know** the answer to my question. I have resolved the underlying problem.

The solution to this problem:
   1.  backup the partition information [  sfdisk -d /dev/sda > sfparts.txt ]
   2.  Using gparted /dev/sda, under the device tab, I used the create partition table entry
   3. At this point both gparted and fdisk showed the same single partition
   4. Using  [ sfdisk /dev/sda < sfparts.txt ] i restored the partition entries
   5. Both gparted and fdisk had exactly the same view of the existing partitions

In the install process, I was able to delete some partitions, create new partitons, create the filesystems and then complete the basic install

thank you to those who responded